# Why does my jQuery work HERE but not THERE?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Newb here. I've been reading about event propagation and I think it may have something to do with this but as much as a I try and as much as I search I can't figure this one out. Why would my jquery work/not work as indicated below? It seems that the for loop is the culprit somehow but why would my data not be visible within it? I am very new to this and appreciate any assistance greatly! Thanks so much for your help!

```
 $.ajax({
 url: RestUrlTwo,
 method: "GET",
 headers: {
 "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
 },
 success: function(dataTwo) {
 if (data.d.results.length > 0) {
 $('#CustomerGrid').append(GenerateTableFromJson(data.d.results,dataTwo.d.results,dataThree.d.results));

 var oTable = $('#AllRequestsTable').dataTable({

initComplete: function() {

    //JQUERY WORKS HERE ******************
    $('input.title').on('input',function(){
        console.log("hi");
    }); 

 }, "iDisplayLength": 100,
 "aLengthMenu": [
 [5, 10, 30, 100],
 [5, 10, 30, 100]
 ],
 "sPaginationType": "full_numbers"
 });
 } 

 }
 });

    $('input.title').on('input',function(){
        console.log("hi");
    });

function GenerateTableFromJson(objArray,objArrayTwo,objArrayThree) {

 var tableContent = '<table summary="GFSTechIntake" id="AllRequestsTable" style="width:100%"><thead><tr><th>Submit Priority</th><th>test</th><th>Your Prev Rank</th><th>Current Overall</th><th>Category</th>' + '<th>Status</th>' +' <th>Request Name</th>' + '<th>Problem Statement</th>' + '<th>Business Benefits</th><th>Dept(s)</th></tr></thead><tbody>';
  var num = [];
 for (var i = 0; i < objArray.length; i++) {    
    for(var j = 0;j < objArrayTwo.length; j++){
        if(objArray[i].Title == objArrayTwo[j].RequestName){
            rank = objArrayTwo[j].Rank ? objArrayTwo[j].Rank : "";
        } 

    }


    //DOESN'T WORK HERE *************
    $('input.title').on('input',function(){
        console.log("hi");
    }); 

    var title = objArray[i].Title ? objArray[i].Title : "";
    var category = objArray[i].Category ? objArray[i].Category : "";
    var status = objArray[i].Status ? objArray[i].Status : "";

     tableContent += '<tr class="allItemsTr">';
     if(rank != ''){
     tableContent += '<td class="allItemsPriority"><span>rank '+rank+'<input class="title" placeholder=' + rank + ' value='+rank+'></td>';
     } else {
     tableContent += '<td class="allItemsPriority"><input class="title" placeholder=' + rank + '></td>';
     }
     tableContent += '<td class="test"></td>';
     tableContent += '<td class="prevRank">N/A</td>';
     tableContent += '<td class="currentRank">N/A</td>';
     tableContent += '<td class="category">'+category+'</td>';
     tableContent += '<td class="allItemsStatus">' + status + '</td>';
     tableContent += '</tr>';
 } 

 return tableContent;

 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because your table hasn't been created at the point you're having issues at.

You set `var tableContent`(and build the **contents** of the table) inside of `function GenerateTableFromJson()`, though you don't actually **add** the table to the DOM until `$('#CustomerGrid').append(GenerateTableFromJson)`. You can't access `$('input.title')` until the element is in the DOM.

**[`initComplete`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/initComplete)** is called once the table has been fully initialised, at which point `<input class="title>` is in the DOM. Thus, `$('input.title')` (`//JQUERY WORKS HERE`) is accessible there.

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: Sure does! One more question though, what would I need to do in order to access where I currently can't? Sorry, I know this is basic level stuff but I can't find answers...frustrating for a beginner.

Comment: You would need to append the table with `.append()` **before** attempting to access `$('input.title')`. Although considering that logic is currently on your AJAX success, it only actually builds the table based on the data actually existing. The way you currently have it what I would say is intentional; if you can't grab the data, you can't set the title. Why would you **want** to access the title if you have failed to create it? There's no **need** to access the element as part of the table creation; simply access it in `initComplete`. You can always modify after creation if need be :)

Comment: Long story short...I've been tasked with building a table (in Sharepoint) with the jquery datatables plugin. Datatables auto sorts all columns by clicking on column header BUT I had to add an input to one of the columns by which users can add ranking numbers for each item. Problem is, if they add some numbers and then want to sort based on the input value (before saving), they can't. Now, thanks to you, I understand why. Datatables is filtering on data that is already there. I was hoping to use jquery to access the input value so that I can somehow use it to make the input column sort. Phew.

Comment: That sounds like an [**XY problem**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378), which you may be approaching the [**wrong way**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/233676). Your question **was** why jQuery won't target the element at that point, which I've answered. I'd expect that datatables would force you to 'save' first, as you need to update the data before you can sort it. It doesn't sound like what you're trying to do is actually possible in that regard, but I'm not too familiar with datatables, so I'd recommend creating a new question, adding **context** to help clarify your **intent**.

Comment: Thanks! you've been very helpful!